# Get original matrix indices within a CUDA device

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, traversal

I am passing a vectorized representation of a `2D square matrix` to a `CUDA` device. I have found online how to perform matrix multiplication with two matrices on this format on a `CUDA` device.

However, I now need to obtain the original indices of my matrix before the device.

This is my code to pass to my `cuda_kernel`

```
#define MATRIX_SIZE 20
#define BLOCK_SIZE 2
#define TILE_SIZE  2

void cuda_stuff(int sz, double **A)
{
  double* A1d = matrix_to_vector(sz, A);
  double* d_A
  size_t sizeA = sz * sz * sizeof(double);
  cudaMalloc(&d_A, sizeA);
  cudaMemcpy(d_A, A1d, sizeA, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  dim3 threads(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
  dim3 grid(MATRIX_SIZE / threads.x, MATRIX_SIZE / threads.y);
  cudakernel<<<grid, threads>>>(sz, d_A);
}
```

This is my `cudakernel`

```
__global__ void cudakernel(int sz, double* A_d);
{
  int tx = blockIdx.x * TILE_SIZE + threadIdx.x;
  int ty = blockIdx.y * TILE_SIZE + threadIdx.y;

  /* Need to get original i, j from my matrix double* A */
}
```

How can I get the original indices [i][j] of my matrix `double* A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will only work properly if `MATRIX_SIZE` is evenly divisible by `BLOCK_SIZE` (and `BLOCK_SIZE` must be the same as `TILE_SIZE`).  This code appears to be set up to handle square matrices only, so I am assuming your original `A` matrix is of size (`MATRIX_SIZE`, `MATRIX_SIZE`).

Given that proviso, the following should retrieve the original element A corresponding to a given thread:

```
double my_A_element  = A_d[ty*MATRIX_SIZE+tx];
```

if you prefer, (again, given the above proviso) you can use the built-in variables:

```
double my_A_element  = A_d[ty*(blockDim.x*gridDim.x)+tx];
```

or, equivalently:

```
double my_A_element  = A_d[ty*sz+tx];
```

Regarding the indices, the `tx` variable is properly defined to give you the original column index into `A`, and the `ty` variable is properly defined to give you the original row index into `A`, for the above defined `my_A_element` variables.

Therefore the original element of `A` (corresponding to `my_A_element`) is just `A[ty][tx]`

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for this. You are correct about all of your assumptions as they are consistent with my matrices. I know how to get the values from A. I was actually hoping to get the indices themselves. The reason is because I am doing a matrix multiplication between a 2D vectorized matrix (A) and a compressed representation of a `tridiagonal matrix`. I represent the tri-matrix as three arrays each corresponding to the values on the diagonal, left of the diagonal, and right of the diagonal. Does this make sense?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand.  I've added some additional comments to my answer, but I don't know if they address your question, since I'm unclear on exactly what the question is, now.

Comment: I appreciate this. I have posted a new question which provides more detail about my entire problem.